# how to maintain same css styles for both yui and jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, yui

We are building some tables using jQuery data tables and some of the tables are using yui 
 data tables.So the tables are displaying in different colors .What i have to do to keep all 
 the tables having same css styles and avoid to overriding styles with each other.

Thanks  in advance..

Comment: Please post some code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: i have lot of code here.I imported jQuery datatables style sheet and yui stylesheet

Comment: Can you not just ensure that both tables and child elements use the same CSS selectors?

Answer (score 0):

I used the classes specified [**HERE**](http://www.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes) .I solved my problem now